# Grabbing emails as input to script

Tags: php, email

I have built up a number of scripts to parse various web requests and emails for use in an SMS gateway.

So for example you enter the URL in the format http://smsget.com/smsget.php?number=xxxxx&message=yyyyy

and one script pulls out the variables and passes to a second to send the SMS.

Currently for SMTP I have set up Exim to redirect the emails received to scripts, but is there a way to use PHP to directly capture and parse and email sent to it, or a light weight module/class so I don't have to use the likes of Exim or other email server/client?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can connect with php_imap on e-mail servers that are enabled with IMAP and handle the messages directly.

You may find some classes to help you on IMAP.

Googled and found this one: https://code.google.com/p/php-imap/, but you may find something better.

Comment: Sorry I should have made this clear, I want to be able to receive smtp mails on the gate way. So the email address would be in the format. 01234567891@smsgateway.com. I know Exim and others can do this, but they have a lot of additional functions I don't need. I jsut want to add an MX recourd so people can send to it from a mail program. email servers will route it around the network and forward the message to the gateway which will accept all emails, parse them and send the text.